# Pandas dataframe compare same keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi i want to compare same keys of a pandas dataframe.

|  | car | values(dict) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | audi1 | {'colour': 'black', 'PS': '3', 'owner': 'peter'} |
| 1 | audi2 | {'owner': 'fred', 'colour': 'black', 'PS': '230', 'number': '3'} |
| 2 | ford | {'windows': '3', 'PS': '3', 'owner': 'peter'} |
| 3 | bmw | {'colour': 'black', 'windows': 'no', 'owner': 'peter', 'number': '3'} |

wanted solution

|  | colour | owner | PS | number | windows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| black | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| peter | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| fred | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| no | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I hope my problem is understandable

```
d = {'audi1': {'colour': 'black', 'PS': '3', 'owner': 'peter'}, 'audi2': {'owner': 'fred', 'colour': 'black', 'PS': '230', 'number': '3'}, 'ford': {'windows': '3', 'PS': '3', 'owner': 'peter'}, 'bmw': {'colour': 'black', 'windows': 'no', 'owner': 'peter', 'number': '3'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['car', 'values'])
```

Comment: Always provide test data. Otherwise users have to type out your data just to test their solution.

Comment: Your desired solution is not understandable. Describe exactly what your are trying to achieve. Also provide your input dictionary in a way that can be copied and pasted. You are much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: ive added the dataframe. i want to compare the items in the dict. Columns as Keys and rows as values and count the values inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe from the dictionaries present in the values column then `stack` the frame to reshape, finally use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create a frequency table:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist()).stack()
table = pd.crosstab(s, s.index.get_level_values(1))
```

Alternate but similar approach with `groupby` + `value_counts` followed by `unstack` to reshape:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist()).stack()
table = s.groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
>>> table

       PS  colour  number  owner  windows
230     1       0       0      0        0
3       2       0       2      0        1
black   0       3       0      0        0
fred    0       0       0      1        0
no      0       0       0      0        1
peter   0       0       0      3        0
```